# Chrome update slowed Ajax/Angular Network rendering and loading

Tags: angularjs, ajax, performance, google-chrome

About two weeks ago, a Chrome update crippled users of my angular app. I load a lot of data but the entire single page application loaded in `< 4` seconds but every single user went to `> 40` seconds after updating Chrome 2 weeks ago. I did not experience the problem, but when I upgraded **Chrome** to `64.0.3282.167` from `63.0.3239.132`, the problem also began for me.

Somewhere between Chrome `63.0.3239.132` and `64.0.3282.167`, there was a change that basically slowed my Angular app to a crawl. It affects loading and rendering across the board and made the entire app almost unusable. I've been looking for the issue for a few days with no joy.

Does anyone have any insight or recommendation on what could cause such a performance degradation?

Here is a screenshot of my network tab. All of this used to be very fast before the Chrome update and now it just crawls.

[image]

If I set:

`httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true)`, it alleviates the problem but my application is huge and this causes a lot of erratic behavior in a 5 year old application.

Comment: Could you add any information about the app? How is it loaded, what modules / libraries used, etc.? Is the content network / computationally heavy?

Comment: Data is primarily loaded after the user logs in, it is indeed network and computation heavy. Angular - Animate, Chart, routing, etc. ui-bootstrap components. Even a spinner.gif that used to take subseconds to load now takes 20 seconds to load if I look at the Chrome console.

Comment: That blue line is the "Content Download", and if it takes this long to download, then this might be a _server-to-client_ issue. Any details about the server?

Comment: Tomcat is the server. The catalyst is definitely the chrome version though or something Chrome doesn't like about the server...

Comment: On Firefox and Safari this problem isn't happening....

Comment: @chrislhardin do you have a lot of extensions installed? Have you tried disabling them / incognito mode? It is really hard to guess what is causing this without having much info about the app. What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Got rid of all extensions... All my users experiences this issue when upgrading. Angular 1.6.9...

Comment: In the “Privacy” section, select the “Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly” option. This may help one way please have a try

Comment: @chrislhardincan you show the network tab in case when `httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true)` is set?

Comment: Can you also record a performance profile so we can see what is going on in the background while this requests are running?

Comment: Did you disable cache too in your Firefox/Safari test?

Comment: have you tried to re-run requests from outside the Chrome? say Telerik Fiddler or another debug proxy. If you have tried to "Replay XHR" from Chrome's Developer tools -> Network -> <content menu for entry> did you see the same delay while fetching data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue, but I know that Google has continued to ramp up security measures with Chrome. This is especially true with HTTPS and I believe Google is pushing for everything to move to HTTPS. Certificates that are not clean (several criteria for this) present problems and may be requiring extra measures to process. I believe there is an add-on (or built-in) for Chrome dev tools that can break out the TLS processing to show you more detail.

Answer (score 0):

A high TTFB reveals one of two primary issues. Either:

1. Bad network conditions between client and server, or A slowly
2. responding server application

To address a high TTFB, first cut out as much network as possible. Ideally, host the application locally and see if there is still a big TTFB. If there is, then the application needs to be optimized for response speed. This could mean optimizing database queries, implementing a cache for certain portions of content, or modifying your web server configuration. There are many reasons a backend can be slow. You will need to do research into your software and figure out what is not meeting your performance budget.

If the TTFB is low locally then the networks between your client and the server are the problem. The network traversal could be hindered by any number of things. There are a lot of points between clients and servers and each one has its own connection limitations and could cause a problem. The simplest method to test reducing this is to put your application on another host and see if the TTFB improves.